# How to apply a autoyast xml without reboot?

Tags: sles11, autoyast

I need to apply some configurations in my environment with Suse, using command line.
I found the following command: yast autoyast file filename=/opt/auth/autoyast.xml

But this command just load my XML, end a need to apply this XML without interaction our reboot, like a bath.

Answer (score 0):

This action can be applied in a system without restart.